# Handling Chat typing or Stop typing event (Android)

Tags: java, android, multithreading, android-edittext

I am handling typing events if user enter text in editext typing function sends requests to server and use removed text i want to stoptyping function do work but its not working.

How to check if user have removed text after entering text

```
mEditText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
                new Thread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        try {
                            session.typing();
                        } catch (OmegleException e) {
                           e.printStackTrace();
                        }catch(NullPointerException e){
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                }).start();
            }
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, 
                int count, int after) {
            }
            public void onTextChanged(final CharSequence s, final int start, 
                int before, int count) {
                new Thread(new Runnable() {

                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        try {
                            if(start==-1){
                                session.stopTyping();
                            }
                        } catch (OmegleException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }catch(NullPointerException e){
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                }).start();
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 1):

I changed to following :

```
mEditText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

            }
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, 
                int count, int after) {
                lengthBeforeType = mEditText.getText().toString().length();

            }
            public void onTextChanged(final CharSequence s, final int start, 
                int before, final int count) {
                lengthAfterType = mEditText.getText().toString().length();
                new Thread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {

                        try {
                            if((lengthAfterType-lengthBeforeType)<0){
                                session.stopTyping();
                            }else{
                                session.typing();
                            }
                        } catch (OmegleException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                }).start();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
int lenghtAfterType;
int lenghtBeforeType;
public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, 
            int count, int after) {
     lenghtBeforeType = yourEdittext.getText.toString.Lenght;
     }
public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
     lenghtAfterType = yourEdittext.getText.toString.Lenght;

     if((lenghtAfterType-lenghtBeforeType)<0){
       // user while deleted text
     }else{
       // user while typing
          }
    }
```

Comment: Your way is fine but you are doing wrong but anyway thanks for that i am posting my answer above you can see what i did to make it work